# Using keys in @CacheEvict to clear a single endpoint's cache

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, caching

Can someone explain a bit more about using keys with the `@CacheEvict(value = "something", key = "idblah")` annotation.

I'm trying to clear the cache for 36 different endpoints.

I already have the one that clears all of them simultaneously but I need to be able to clear each endpoint's cache separately.

Comment: Does all the 36 endpoints have same cache or different ?

Comment: Hi @Bond-JavaBond please see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

So, I was able to figure out how to use it. All 36 endpoints have different cache. So, I used:

```
@Caching(evict = {@CacheEvict(value = 'accessory1', key = "'acc1'"), @CacheEvict(value = 'accessory2', key = "'acc2'"), //etc..})
```

And for each method in my services class I included the key next to the cache. Like this:

```
@Cacheable(value = "accesory1", key = "'acc1'")
public Accessory1 callAccessory1(String input1) throws ParserConfigurationException, IOException{
//method logic
}
```

The single quotes inside the key are for it to accept the key as a string. It works fine, if you have any input please don't hessitate to comment.

Thanks everyone!